# FFmpeg/Avconv unable to copy subtitles due to unsupported codec?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv, video-editing

I've got an mp4 file with these streams (`avconv -i file.mp4` or `ffmpeg -i file.mp4`):

```
Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s
Stream #0.2(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x568, 4027 kb/s, PAR 1:1 DAR 160:71, 23.98 fps, 2997 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Stream #0.3(eng): Subtitle: c608 / 0x38303663, 0 kb/s
Stream #0.4(und): Subtitle: text / 0x74786574
Stream #0.5: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 667x1000 [PAR 72:72 DAR 667:1000], 90k tbn
```

I am trying to strip out the first audio stream from the file like so:

```
avconv -i file.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:0 -codec copy file-out.mp4

# OR #

ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:0 -codec copy file-out.mp4
```

The problem is, I get this error:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

So, I checked if something's wrong with the mp4 file itself:

```
avprobe file.mp4

# OR #

ffprobe file.mp4
```

And the output says:

```
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 94213 for input stream 4
```

I have no idea what that means. (Apparently something's wrong with the subtitles, but I got the video from iTunes.)

1. What's wrong?
2. Can I simply force avconv/ffmpeg to do what I asked of it (i.e. strip the audio stream & copy the rest as it is)? If so, how?

---

Apparently I missed the other errors/warnings in the console output before the final error message, like @aergistal suggested:

```
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 2 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 3 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] Codec for stream 4 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x2645420] track 2: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container
```

Comment: Crossposting the [same question](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/ffmpeg-avconv-unable-to-copy-subtitles-unsupported-codec) on multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged, and this particular question is offtopic here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ffmpeg`, first thing make sure you have a recent version (try the [git snapshot](http://git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git)).

One thing you can try is to use the `-copy_unknown` option, but I don't think it'll help in this case.

My hunch is that it doesn't allow some codecs in `mp4`. See if you don't have other errors/warnings in the console output before the final error message, like `codec not currently supported in container`.

If that's the case try to write them to a `mov` file.

Comment: Oh, you are so right! (Please see updated question.) So, is there no way I can simply strip the audio file and remux the rest to the same container?

Comment: I'm afraid they're not officially supported in MP4. FFmpeg allows only `dvd_subtitle` and `mov_text` in this case. Unless you want to modify it, ofc .